# getJSON File Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my JSON code for area.json:

```
 {"myArea":[{
   "name": "ny 01",
   "data": [63]
 }]}
```

and for center.json:

```
{"myCenter":[{
 "name": "garden state plaza 1",
 "data": [84]
 }]}
```

When I try to access one file it works:

```
$.when($.getJSON('json/area.json')).then(function(area){                     
    console.log(area['myArea']);
});
```

But when I try to retrieve two files console returns undefined.

```
$.when($.getJSON('json/area.json'), $.getJSON('json/center.json')).then(function(area,center){                     
    console.log(area['myArea']);
    console.log(center['myCenter']);
});
```

Why am I receiving undefined?

Comment: Is your `then` function being called? How about implementing the second parameter, to track any failures? http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/

Comment: second parameter returns the same undefined.

Comment: try to access your second file individually and debug the returned object, it might not contain what you posted as center.json

Comment: Have you tried to use something like fiddler to capture the ajax requests and see what is actually being returned by the requests?

Comment: The odd thing is if I remove `{'myArea':` and closing `}` from both json files it works. So why can't it read the JSON file with the class names when adding more than one file?

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT** as smartly pointed out by another SO friend, this must not be the problem. so disregard this answer.

...probably one or both of your get requests is failing. To make sure, add a failure handler to the then

```
$.when($.getJSON('json/area.json'),$.getJSON('json/center.json'))
 .then( function(area,center){                     
           console.log(area['myArea']);
           console.log(center['myCenter']);
         },
        function(err) {
           console.log(err);
         });
```

Comment: He indicated that "console returns undefined".  So I would assume this means that his `then` function is calling the done handler.  If it were failing he would not get any console logging at all.

Comment: your are right, .done() is invoked, so .fail() is not. It's probably in the code where the problem is. Disregard my answer, it is misleading.

Comment: I am receiving the same undefined.

Comment: try to access your second file individually and debug the returned object, it might not contain what you posted as center.json

Answer (score -2):

Thanks for your help everyone. The issue was that I had and quote in the second file where I shouldn't have had it.